# EKF Sub-sampling?

Tags: ros, navigation, ekf, kalman, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I'm publishing odometry at 100 Hz and /robot_pose_ekf/odom only publishes a filtered value for roughly 1 in every four messages I give it.

running:
rosservice call /robot_pose_ekf/get_status

gives the following output:

status: Input:

- Odometry sensor

  - is active
  - received 5965 messages
  - listens to topic /odom
- IMU sensor

  - is NOT active
  - received 0 messages
  - listens to topic
- Visual Odometry sensor

  - is NOT active
  - received 0 messages
  - listens to topic

Output:

- Robot pose ekf filter

  - is active
  - sent 1751 messages
  - pulishes on topics /robot_pose_ekf/odom and /tf

So it appears that it's receiving my messages successfully. Should I expect 1:1 output? I set the freq to 100 in the ekf .launch file.

I'd be happy to publish a bag file of my odometry if that helps.

Still running fuerte...

Any thoughts would be appreciated,

Cheers,

Willy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74413/ekf-sub-sampling?/) by [uuilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/4356/uuilly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actual answer:

robot_pose_ekf has a 'freq' parameter you can set:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf#Configuration

http://www.ros.org/wiki/Parameter%20Server#Private_Parameters

---

Sidenote:

Do you have an IMU on your robot?  Otherwise, robot_pose_ekf won't accomplish anything for you with just one odometry source.

If you need a base_footprint tf frame, use static tf publisher from /base_link:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uuilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/4356/uuilly/) on 2013-08-23**:
Thanks Chad,
Like I said, I set the freq to 100 in the .launch file. As for other sensors, we're going to add visual odometry but I wanted to make sure everything worked first. A Kalman filter should help just the encoder b/c it uses its previous estimate to influence the current estimate.

I definitely do not have a base footprint frame. Our system doesn't need one. But I can add one if it makes ekf happier.

Would any of these things prevent a 1:1 input to output ratio?

**Comment by [uuilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/4356/uuilly/) on 2013-08-23**:
So I lowered the frequency that I published encoder ticks. Looks like ekf maxes out at about 20 Hz on my hardware.